# outer measure problem when 2 sets are positively separated

Tags: measure-theory

let $A,B\subset\Bbb R^n$, $d(A,B)>0$, then $\mu^*(A\bigcup B)=\mu^*(A)+\mu^*(B)$

one inequality is trivial $\mu^*(A\bigcup B)\le\mu^*(A)+\mu^*(B)$

so I need to prove the reverse inequality $\mu^*(A\bigcup B)\ge\mu^*(A)+\mu^*(B)$ but I don't know how to start

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Cover $A\cup B$ by boxes that have small diameter, so that no box intersects both $A$ and $B$.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding this, Why can I do that? I mean, How can I assure this boxes exist?

Comment: If $\mu^*(A\cup B)=\infty$ then you have nothing to prove. In case it is finite, use the definition of $\mu^*$ which gives you the boxes. You have to do some $\varepsilon$-argument, and then let $\varepsilon\to 0$.

Comment: @DimitriosNt I understand the argument you've made but don't quite know how to write it. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Let $\delta= d(A,B)>0$. Cover $A\cup B$ by boxes $B_i,i\in I$ such that each $B_i$ has diameter less than $\delta/2$, so it cannot intersect both $A$ and $B$ (Of course  in the definition of the outer measure you have to consider boxes of any size, but then you can cut each box into smaller boxes until they have small enough diameter). Thus, the cover of $A\cup B$ gives you covers for $A$ and $B$.