# outer measure problem when two sets are disjoint.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

[outer measure problem when 2 sets are positively separated](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/711866/outer-measure-problem-when-2-sets-are-positively-separated) In this question if we assume that two sets are not positively separated but intersection is zero will there be  a contradiction.

My try: First of all the set should not be measurable. But if it is not i do not know how to associate an outermeasure.If anyone can help it would be great. Thanks

Comment: Do you mean that their intersection has measure zero?

Comment: @Marc I mean the intersection is empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you ask whether $ \mu^*(A\bigcup B)=\mu^*(A)+\mu^*(B)$ holds when $A$ and $B$ are disjoint. It does not.

Take a [Vitali set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set) $V$. Since a line segment can be covered by countably many sets $V+q_k$, the subadditivity of $\sigma$ implies  $\mu^*(V)>0$. On the other hand, the **disjoint** union of $V+q_k$ is contained in  a line segment of length $k$. Take an integer $n$ such that $n\mu^*(V)>3$. Then 
$$\mu^*\left( \bigcup_{k=1}^n (V+q_k)\right)\le 3 < \sum_{k=1}^n \mu^* (V+q_k)$$
which means that additivity fails for finite disjoint unions.