# Folland 1.17: The intersection of any set with a sequence of measurable set implies additivity.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

The original problem is pretty easy to understand:

Let $A$ be any set in $\mathbb R^n$ and $\{E_i\}_{i = 1} ^{\infty}$ be a sequence of **disjoint** and **measurable** sets. Let $m_{*}$ denote the Lebesgue outer measure. We would like to prove the following:

$$
m_{*}(A\cap(\cup_{i=1} ^ {\infty} E_{i})) = \sum_{i = 1} ^ {\infty} m_{*}(A \cap E_i).
$$

I referred to the solution [here](http://mathfin.ca/docs/Real_Analysis.pdf) (page 8, Proposition 1.9), and in this solution, there's one line that confuses me a lot. My equivalent translation is as follows:

Let $B_n := \displaystyle \cup_{i = 1} ^ {n} E_i $, then $$m_{*}(A \cap B_n) = m_{*}(A \cap B_n \cap E_n) + m_{*}(A \cap B_n \cap E_n^C).$$

**I would like to know how we get this equation.** My confusion is that the outer measure does not support the additivity of disjoint sets whose distances are not positive. Here, I can only have $A \cap B_n \cap E_n$ and $A \cap B_n \cap E_n^C$ are disjoint, how can we directly apply that additivity?

For additivity does not apply to JUST disjoint sets: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/832402/686556

Comment: This is the Caratheodory condition for $E_n$ being measurable. However I am not sure how it proceeded in the book.

Comment: @Yuval Thanks! Could you elaborate on why $A \cap B_n$  satisfy the Caratheodory condition?

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the comments, the equation is the Caratheodory condition for measurability: namely, $E_n$ is considered to be $m_\ast$-measurable if and only if every subset $\hat A$ of $\mathbb R^n$,

$$m_\ast(\hat A) = m_\ast(\hat A \cap E_n) + m_\ast(\hat A \cap {E_n}^C).$$

Replace $\hat A$ with $A \cap B_n$ and you're done.

Comment: Yeah, but how can you get $m_*(A \cap \cup_{i = 1}^{n-1} Ei) + m_*(A \cap E_n) = m_*(A \cap \cup_{i = 1}^{n} Ei)$?

Comment: I think I'm actually asking about how can we directly split the outer measure into the outer measure of two DISJOINT sets. I'm not asking about the recursion step afterwards, which is what you have answered.

Comment: But the outer measure does not support additivity for JUST disjoint sets. You need to have $d(A, B) > 0$ to apply the additivity. What you have written just gave disjointness.

Comment: Check here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/832402/686556

Comment: Ah, I see. I'll edit again

Comment: Thanks! It means that we have to prove first that $A \cap B_n$ is Caratheodory measurable, then we can have the equation. How can I prove that it's Caratheodory measurable?

Comment: By showing the condition defines a σ-algebra, essentially. Is that not addressed elsewhere in the book?

Comment: No... I would appreciate so much if you can extend on how to prove that it's $\sigma$-algebra and to prove the Caratheodory Measuability. Thanks!!

Comment: No wait, it doesn't need to be measurable! The condition applies for _all_ subsets $\hat A$, measurable or not.